# Can't assign to return value because function 'operator->' returns a const value

Tags: c++

I am trying to do dfs over a graph defined as `unordered_map<string,set<pair<string,int>>> g;`

So here is my dfs code:

```
void dfs(string u){
        for(auto v=g[u].begin();v!=g[u].end();v++){
            if(!v->second){
                cout<<v->first<<endl;
                res.push_back(v->first);
                v->second = 1; 
                dfs(v->first);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to change the value of v->second to 1, but I am getting an error of

```
cannot assign to return value because function 'operator->' returns a const value
                v->second = 1;
```

So is there any other way to change the second value of the pair?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot modify value of an element of `std::set` as it would break it's invariant. What you can do though is to remove existing element and insert modified one. But as you iterate over the `set` then such modification inside loop would be overcomplicated. So I suggest you remove all elements that satisfy your condition and then insert them all back modified.

Though it is not clear why you need `int` value of `std::pair` to be a part of the key. If that is a mistake, then just use `std::unordered_map<string,std::map<string,int>>` insted and then you can modify `v->second` without any problem (but that value would not be a part of the key anymore).

Note your loop is written quite ineffective way - you are invoking `std::unordered_map::operator[]` on every iteration. Instead you better get a reference to that element and use it:

```
void dfs(string u){
        auto &gu = g[u];
        for(auto v=gu.begin();v!=gu.end();v++){
...
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from `begin()` method of `set`. As stated in [cpp ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/begin):

> Because both iterator and const_iterator are constant iterators (and may in fact be the same type), it is not possible to mutate the elements of the container through an iterator returned by any of these member functions.

This means the `v` is in fact `const`, so `operator->()` will be `const` version too. So you will not be able to change `second`.

BTW, a suggestion: use `bool` for visiting not `int`. it helps readability.